# Ошибка при использовании регулярных выражений: re.error: bad escape \p at position 0 re.error: bad escape \p at position 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, python-3.8

```py
import re
re.match(r'\p{script=Latin}', "Latin text")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 191, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 304, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 948, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 525, in _parse
    code = _escape(source, this, state)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 426, in _escape
    raise source.error("bad escape %s" % escape, len(escape))
re.error: bad escape \p at position 0
```

Как видно модуль `re` не поддерживает `\p` ([соответствие определенным Unicode Properties](https://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#property_syntax), используется для удобной работы с юникод в RE).

Как исправить?

Python 3.8

Comment: Как-то странно, что экейп-последовательность распознается в raw-строке. Или это ошибка интерпритатора регулярок?

Comment: без r тоже самое, @cauf.

Comment: Эта последовательность символов в принципе не является валидным паттерном. А что именно вы хотели обозначить набором символов `\p`?

Comment: @cauf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981258/how-can-i-specify-cyrillic-character-ranges-in-a-python-3-2-regex

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Там же в ответе и написано, что это сторонний модуль `regex`, а не builtin `re`.

Comment: И всё же в тексте вопроса не помешало бы краткое упоминание, кто вообще такой этот ваш `\p`

Comment: @andreymal это фильтр юникодных codepoint =) Со `\p{Cyrillic}` было бы понятнее)

Comment: @vp_arth ну загуглить я и сам могу, но качественная база знаний предполагает упоминание сути в тексте вопроса)

Comment: @vp_arth но я что-то не пойму как это работает, какое-нибудь `\p{AHex=Y}` работает, а `\p{Age=V1_1}` не работает...

Comment: Не знаю ни AHex, ни Age(ни script, честно говоря) =) Я [вот тут](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) их подглядываю

Comment: Видимо, просто поддержка неполная. Но какая есть)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попопробуйте использовать модуль [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

```
import regex

In [137]: regex.match(r'\p{script=Latin}', "Latin text")
Out[137]: <regex.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='L'>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное — выручил!

Comment: Я там вопрос подправил — приоткроешь?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor однако так и не стало ясно, кто вообще такой этот ваш `\p`

Comment: @andreymal https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1205022/revisions

Comment: @VictorVosMottor всё равно не ясно, стандартный `re` вполне поддерживает юникод, какое-нибудь юникодное `[А-Яа-яЁё]` успешно работает)

Comment: А теперь давай с китайскими ;D @andreymal